# how can I just ignored the specified error in jsHint?

Tags: jshint

I use `require.js` in my job, when I run `jshint`
it will tell me this:
`line 11, col 1, 'define' is not defined.`
I want to do this:
if is `define` not defined, ignore,
if is others not defined, tell me the error
how can I write in `jshint.rc`?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is because `define` **is** actually defined, just not in that file.

You need to tell jsHint that `define` is a valid global symbol.

Add this line at the beginning:

```
/* global define */
```

or

```
/* global define,$,require,whatever */
```

to prime the global symbol check table.

In jshint.rc, you can set:

```
{
    "define"       : true
}
```

or if define is not a known library,

```
{
    "predef"        : [
         "define"
    ]
}
```

(see for example [this link](https://gist.github.com/connor/1597131)).

Comment: @lsemi can I set this in `jshint.rc`?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, forgot. Edited answer

Comment: @lsemi and how can I ignore `is defined but never used` in `jshint.rc`?

Comment: Do not take this wrong, but have you checked out jsHint 's documentation? You'll find this and several other useful options.